# Media Player Forbidden Error (403)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have been streaming music for quite sometime from my server but now for some strange reason, i am getting an error 403. On the logcat, i have this,

```
01-07 11:07:44.077 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [seekToEx] HTTP header =>User-Agent: LG-D855/V21a Player/LG Player 1.0 for Android 5.0 (stagefright alternative)
01-07 11:07:48.794 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response code] STATUS CODE:403
01-07 11:07:48.795 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] null: [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden]
01-07 11:07:48.795 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] Connection: [close]
01-07 11:07:48.795 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] Content-Length: [0]
01-07 11:07:48.795 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] Content-Type: [text/plain]
01-07 11:07:48.796 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] Date: [Thu, 07 Jan 2016 08:07:50 GMT]
01-07 11:07:48.796 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] Last-Modified: [Wed, 02 May 2007 10:26:10 GMT]
01-07 11:07:48.796 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] Server: [gvs 1.0]
01-07 11:07:48.796 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] X-Android-Received-Millis: [1452154068792]
01-07 11:07:48.796 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] X-Android-Response-Source: [NETWORK 403]
01-07 11:07:48.797 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] X-Android-Sent-Millis: [1452154067394]
01-07 11:07:48.797 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [response header] X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
01-07 11:07:48.797 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnectionEx: [ResponseMessage]:Forbidden
01-07 11:07:48.798 15543-15688/com.radioafrica.music D/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 0 / 32768 => -1
```

and i can't seem to get any stream to play. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: the server is kicking you out

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Error 403 means **Forbidden**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4)

The server is denying you access to the resource. This could be cause by different things -

1. Not being authenticated
2. IP Block
3. User Agent Block
4. Server Issue ( filesystem permissions )

If you say this is a new issue without you having made a code change - the hosting service could have also made a change that is now blocking your player.

Are you able to fetch the stream from a real browser? From a PC? Different IP?